# How to prevent React app crashing when react-router is used

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8iU0.png)I am trying to include React-router in my React app , and i am using it in the navigation component, but after using it and initializing the path , my react app is crashing . Please refer code below :

Have tried writing according t react-router v4 syntax , the  is used in the App.js file and the Link and Route have been used in Navigation.js component .

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Navigation.css';
import App from '../../App';
import Create from '../pages/create/Create';
import List from '../pages/list/List';


class Navigation extends Component{
    render(){
    return (
          <div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
              <Link className="navbar-brand mr-auto" to="/">HOME</Link>
              <div id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul className="navbar-nav">
                  <li className="nav-item active">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/Create">Create</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item" >
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/List">List</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            {/* <Route path="/" exact component={App} /> */}
            <Route path="/Create" component={Create} />
            <Route path="/List" component={List} />
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navigation from './js/navigation/Navigation.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navigation/>
          <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
            <hr class="my-4"/>
            <p>Please Click on Create to Create the Schema and on List to View the Schema.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

when i run the app and click on Create or List , respective components should be rendered but app is crashing when i run the react-app.

Comment: Can you share your app component code?

Comment: Please reproduce your issue in stackblitz.

Comment: Have added my App.js component as requested. @PraveenRaoChavan.G

Comment: @nishant what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G - React app is not launching when i include my route path , it is crashing .

Comment: @nishanth Can I have a look at index.js ?

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G     index.js:                                                                       
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: @Justcode when i tried there its working , but when the same method is not working in my editor -- https://react-wk8fyb.stackblitz.io

Comment: @nishant what error you are getting?

Comment: @Justcode , have added the screenshot , Please have a check .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your crash **screenshot**, Your app is entering an infinite loop in your **Create Component**, please check your create component code

Comment: Nope still the same , react app crashes when i click on Create or List :(

Comment: What do you mean by crash? please share a screenshot

Comment: as long as i remove the component attribute  in my Navigation.js file's Route component , it works , but when i include it again it crashes

Comment: Please create a pen https://codepen.io/ OR stackblitz, share your complete code, it will help us to check, also please share screen shot of your crash

Comment: have shared the screenshot of the crash

Comment: yes i believe i had called the Navigation component in Create as well which resulted in infinite loop , have removed it and it is working properly now , Thank you :)